# Python nose configuration file only allow WHERE to be speciifed once

Tags: python, nose

In nose.cfg

```
[nosetests]
where=path1
where=path2
where=path3
```

Only the last definition is used. The docs say that the --where flag can be used multiple times, but this doesn't seem to work in configuration files?

Comment: Have you tried something like: `where=path1;path2...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support for multiple "where" arguments is [deprecated](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/f349692bd42edb04252d740c1d401079142eb24b/nose/config.py#L430-L435):

```
warn("Use of multiple -w arguments is deprecated and "
     "support may be removed in a future release. You can "
     "get the same behavior by passing directories without "
     "the -w argument on the command line, or by using the "
     "--tests argument in a configuration file.",
     DeprecationWarning)
```

Specify `where` once - to define a working directory and define other paths under `tests`:

```
[nosetests]
where=path1
tests=path2,path3
```

Comment: Did you try it? I get: ValueError: Working directory 'path1,path2,path3' not found, or not a directory. I also read the deprecation warning, but don't see what the intended replacement is.

Comment: @rsb okay what I definitely tried was to help you. Have you tried passing the same comma-separated value via command-line `--where=path1,path2,path3` (at least, for the sake of debugging the problem)? Have you tried providing which version of nose are you using? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @alecxe, sorry I think "did you try it" came off sounding the wrong way (I wanted to know if it worked for you), I appreciate your suggestion. Yes, I tried all the combinations (with/without brackets, quotes, etc.) nosetests version 1.3.7

Comment: @rsb sorry for being too sarcastic and offensive. Let me debug it a little bit. To clarify: it's throwing the same ValueError if you do it from the command-line?..

Comment: Hey thanks very much, that worked. I had thought tests had to be filenames not directories. Cheers alecxe.